# How to delete all the document in collection ? (flutter / firebase collection)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have one function is to upload the excel file into the firebase cloud firestore collection. Before i insert the data , i should clear all the document in the cloud firestore collection first . Is there any function or method can clear all the collection or document in one shot ?

```
void _importData() async {
    for (var table in data.tables.keys) {
      for (var row in data.tables[table].rows) {
        print("$row");

        await databaseReference.collection("vehicles").add({
          //row[i] = the column sequence in the excel
          'Car_Make': row[3],
          'Company': row[4],
          'Holder_Type': row[2],
          'Holder_Name': row[1],
          'Vehicle_No': row[0],
        }).then((value) => print("Upload Complete"));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this documentation, https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+delete+collection

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not support deleting a whole Collection. You will have to get all the documents and delete each of them individually.

You may try the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vehicles').snapshots().forEach((querySnapshot) {
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
    docSnapshot.reference.delete();
  }
});
```

Comment: Undefined class 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: What Firebase packages do you have in your `pubspec.yaml`?